# Why is `3[arr]` notation of accessing elements in array is not used?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, c

Today, I came across the notation `3[arr]` in C++, and I was surprised to find out that it's a valid way to access array elements. For example:

```cpp
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
int element = 1[arr]; // This compiles and works!
```

Online IDE: https://onlinegdb.com/4o8qnsx8O

The assembly of this looks exactly same

```
arr:
        .long   10
        .long   20
        .long   30
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 16
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR arr+4    ; getting 20 from arr variable, store in eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-4], eax  ; store eax to variable "a"
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR arr+4    ; getting 20 from arr variable, store in eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp-8], eax  ; store eax to variable "b"
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Disassembly from Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/dEaYjashs

While this notation seems to work, it's somewhat unconventional, and I'm curious if it's considered a good practice in C++ programming. In natural language, we say "Accessing 3rd element of array arr", then isn't `3[arr]` notation fits better here?

My questions are:

1. Is using `3[arr]` a valid and safe practice in C++?
2. Are there any specific situations or use cases where this notation might be advantageous?
3. Is there any guideline or convention against using `3[arr]` that I should be aware of?

I haven't encountered this notation in any code I've seen so far, so any insights or advice on its usage would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is, yes, don't use it.  As you might discover, `a[i]` is simply the memory location `a + i`.

Comment: You did not explain problem with `i[a]`.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19782170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since addition is commutative, we can use any accessor method. But in programming, the more code is **human-understandable**, the better it is ranked. And that is why guidelines exist.

In this case, using `arr[3]` is more readable than `3[arr]`. Instead of array, let's think in term of hashmaps: Suppose you are asked to get  *third key* key in the *my_map* (and you can use same notion of in hashmap key access), which is more readable `"third key"[my_map]` or my_map["third key"].  To me, its second one.

Answer (score -1):

The C++ standard says "The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(E1 + E2)`...". So `3[arr]` is `*(3+arr)` is `*(arr+3)` is `arr[3]`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: This is outside the scope of cs.

Comment: @PålGD: right, I missed that.